# viewDidLoad in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

What is `ViewDidLoad()` method for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is executed, when the view controller loaded your view sucessfully - and you can do there your custom initializations as well.

If you are new to iPhone development, take a look at the apple reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I have seen too many times `-viewDidLoad` used to setup the view controller's title, navigationItem, tabBarItem or any of the properties of these, such as the right/leftBarButtonItems on navigationItem. This is is not advised, because these properties may be needed before the view is loaded.

As an example, a tab bar controller needs each view controller's tabBarItem but won't load the view to the unselected tabs; So `-viewDidLoad` won't be called before the tabBarItem is needed.

Answer (score -1):

It's called when the view loaded. Is it really that complicated??